# Mountain Lion: Use standard keyboard function keys, F1, F2, etc.?

Tags: macos, preferences, keybindings, keyboard

I'm having issues with Mountain lion in which I am unable to use my non-Apple keyboard's function keys, i.e. <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> etc.  Upon firing up `System Preferences` ➤ `Keyboard`, this is what I'm greeted with.
[image]

In prior versions of the operating system there had been an option here to

> Use all F1, F2 keys as standard function keys...

...which enabled me to utilize the Functions keys, as expected, instead of triggering whatever "Hot Key" usually hijacks that binding ordinarily.

[image]

**How can I get this capability back under 10.8.x?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still shown for me. Have you tried changing the keyboard type or running `defaults write -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState -bool true` and logging out and back in?

Comment: As of 10.8.3..  it's back.  I probably did run your `defaults` command… but don't remember if that's what "fixed it"…  so.. you WIN!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Logitech keyboard.  In that case, the option in question is not in the preference pane, as you note.  But there is an option to set this in the Logitech setup utility.  What "non-Apple keyboard" are you using?